PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException unable to find valid certification path to requested target
i'm trying to get a orderId from Razorpay api through java but ended up with this error.RazorpayException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
i have also set the razorpay.crt in my lib/security path of my jdk-18 still getting this error

Please provide more debugging details so we can better answer your question. Good debugging questions contain both a [mre] and a full error traceback, both posted as [code-fenced text}(/editing-help#code) (not images).

the error is resolved, ive added the cacert path in code itself
Thank you for your response

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\lib\security\cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
i added these lines in my method
it is now working fine
